# Multi-arch bin directories

Tags: directory-structure

I have a NFS-mounted home directory where I keep some executable programs for different OS and machine architectures. (A particular executable is built for one particular architecture only.) I have to store these executables in different bin directories (one bin directory for each OS/machine combination) so that I can easily put those directories in `PATH`.

*Is there a conventional place to put executables for a particular OS/architecture?*

The best I could find was [MultiarchSpec - Filesystem layout | Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Filesystem_layout). It's only for libraries, e.g. `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` - it doesn't say anything about executables.

Currently I have this:

```sh
d=~/".local/$(uname | tr A-Z a-z)-$(uname -m | tr A-Z a-z)/bin"
if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    export PATH="$PATH":"$d"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the current version of the [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) does not discuss locations of binaries for different architectures, a related issue came up in their [bugtracker](https://bugs.linuxfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=796). This proposal could be extended to include the `OS` as well, but that should be discussed in the [FHS mailing list](https://lists.linux-foundation.org/mailman/listinfo/fhs-discuss).

In short: no standard exists (yet) and every site is free to choose its own, whatever is suited best for the particular requirement. If your `PATH` setup above works for you, it's the right setup :-)